# Determine convergence of $a_n\,$ defined as $\,a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n(a_n^2+3a)}{3a_{n}^2+a} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I had this question in one of my assignments

[image]

I was able to deduce that

- Since, $a_1 \gt 0$, implies that $\,\,a_n \gt 0\,\, \forall\,n$
- $a_n$ increases in the interval $(0,\sqrt a \,)$
- Decreases when $a_n > \sqrt a$.
- If $a_n$ converges then the possible limits are $\pm \sqrt a$, but since $\,\,a_n \gt 0 \,\,\forall\,n \implies$ the only possible value for limit in this case is $\sqrt a$

The thing I'm struggling to prove is if $0\lt a_1 \lt \sqrt a$ then the sequence is bounded above by $\sqrt a$.
I tried proving it using induction, but I'm stuck at the induction step. i.e.
If we assume $a_n \lt \sqrt a ,\,\,$ how do we prove that $a_{n+1} \lt \sqrt a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}=\frac{(a_n-\sqrt{a})^3}{3a_n^2+a}$$
Then, if $a_n <\sqrt{a}$, you deduce directly that $a_{n+1}<\sqrt{a}$

Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Induction is not needed for solving this part. Define $b_n=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt a}$. The recurrence for $b_n$ would be $b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n^3+3b_n}{3b_n^2+1}$. Prove that $0\le b_n\le 1$ implies $0\le b_{n+1}\le 1$ by proving that the function $f(x)=\frac{x^3+3x}{3x^2+1}$ is strictly increasing for $x\in[0,1]$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.